# Storing periodicity in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, whenever

I am giving users an option to receive, say, emails at a periodicity of their choice, for example:

```
Every day at 5am
```

or

```
Every Friday at 11pm
```

or even

```
Every second Monday of the month at 12am
```

What would be my best choice for storing this kind of data in order to feed it to `Whenever` gem?

**Update**

I was able to solve the question with @mudasobwa 's advice in combination with the `cron_parser` gem. The process flow is:

- Get user's input from a select box on the frontend
- Parse it on the backend and de-code into cron format (e.g. `7` would mean that I will need to send emails every week, so the code could be "`1 1 * * 1`"), store the value as `periodicity`.
- Use the `cron_parser` gem to generate the `next_run` dateformat which is used to tell whenever gem which jobs it needs to perform that are dated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whenever` gem [accepts](https://github.com/javan/whenever#example-schedulerb-file) a raw cron syntax. That is why the simplest way, involving as few transformations as possible, would be to store values in *raw cron format*.

That said, you probably should have a parser from/to allowed user input to/from raw cron format and that’s it.

Comment: yes in theory that's pretty clear but what should I store within the database? My process is that whenever checks every hour for recipients that had yet to receive their messages (so it looks for outdated messages) and sends them away. Those messages have a column called next_send which stores the date/time when the message should be sent out. But to get the date in that column I need to parse it from the initial user input.

Comment: Within the database you should store **strings in raw cron format** as stated in my answer twice. Smth like `"0 0 27-31 * *"`.

Comment: Thanks, so in a nutshell I would store this raw cron data and parse it in order to get the next_run date and set it on my model?

Comment: Well, I can’t use a wording “you do,” but yes, if I was to implement this, I would store the raw cron data and parse it to retrieve the human-readable values, like date and time.

Comment: Welcome, не за что.